# Why is magnetostatics defined as $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, definition, magnetostatics

I don't see why the idea of steady currents (i.e. magnetostatics) implies that charge density $\rho(\vec{r},t)$ has no explicit time dependence.

Is it just coming from [magnetostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) being defined as $ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J}:= 0$ (I don't see why this would be true either) and because of the continuity equation $\implies \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = 0$.

Introduction to Electrodynamics, D.J. Griffiths section 5.2.1 - Steady Currents

[image: D.J. Griffiths section 5.2.1 paragraph above equation 5.31]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the charge density cannot be static in the case of nonzero currents. Where did you find this?

Comment: @NDewolf I found this is D.J. Griffiths book, Introduction to Electrodynamics section 5.2.1 in the paragraph above equation 5.31 (I will attach a picture of it in my question).

Comment: @franz I just don't see how charge density having some explicit time dependence would imply the currents would not be static. If possible, could you please elaborate? (sorry if this is a trivial question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnetostatics is, in some sense, a toy concept taught to students in preparation for the formal magneto-quasi-static (MQS) approximation. The purpose of the MQS approximation is to decouple the electrical field from the magnetic field. This is done by setting $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec E \approx 0$ so that Ampere's law becomes $\nabla \times \vec H \approx \vec J$ (see http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter3/3.2.html )

Since we want $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec E \approx 0$ and also $\epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot \vec E = \rho$ then that implies that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho \approx 0$

By decoupling the fields it becomes much easier to solve. So this approximation is very useful to make. Allowing $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho \ne 0$ would result in $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec E \ne 0$ and thus the fields would be coupled again. So this assumption actually turns out to be more important that the steady current assumption $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec J \approx 0$ assumption. In fact, in the MQS the latter assumption is not made and the currents are allowed to change over time, but the equations remain decoupled and simple to solve at each time point.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally define a “steady current” as one that obeys $\frac\partial{\partial t} \mathbf J = 0$ everywhere.

The requirement that the charge density in “magnetostatics” not change with time, $\frac\partial{\partial t} \rho = 0$, allows the student to use the tools developed during *electro*statics to figure out what the electric fields do.

Most elementary treatments (including Griffiths) begin with a chapter or two of electrostatics with $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho =0$ and $\mathbf J = 0$. Next follows a chapter or two of magnetostatics with $\mathbf J\neq0$ but $\mathbf J$ and $\rho$ both held constant. Then the charging-or-discharging capacitor is introduced as an example where there are regions of $\frac\partial{\partial t}\rho \neq 0$ and therefore $\frac\partial{\partial t}\mathbf E \neq 0$, motivating Maxwell’s discovery of the need for the displacement current. This pedagogical strategy mirrors the historical timeline of the development of the theory.